# Right way to use Metal

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I have different types of drawings that I do in my app. For example, I draw shapes and grids.

For each type of drawing I have a custom vertex and fragment shader and a class that inherits from MTKViewDelegate. Each of these classes deals with the processing needed to calculate the inputs and a method that looks like this and is called on init:

```
private func loadMetal(_ mtkView: MTKView) {
    mtkView.colorPixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm_srgb

    let defaultLibrary = device.makeDefaultLibrary()!
    let vertexProgram = defaultLibrary.makeFunction(name: "grid_vertex")
    let fragmentProgram = defaultLibrary.makeFunction(name: "grid_fragment")

    let pipelineStateDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
    pipelineStateDescriptor.vertexFunction = vertexProgram
    pipelineStateDescriptor.fragmentFunction = fragmentProgram
    pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = mtkView.colorPixelFormat

    pipelineState = try! device.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: pipelineStateDescriptor)

    commandQueue = device.makeCommandQueue()

    vertexBuffer = device.makeBuffer(length: bufferCapacity * MemoryLayout<GridVertex>.stride, options: [])

    vertexIndices = device.makeBuffer(length: bufferCapacity * MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size,
                                      options: [])
}
```

So for each pair of vertex/frag shaders I'm creating the pipelineDescriptor and a commandQueue. This works ok, but I was wondering if this is ok or should I reuse the commandQueue/pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reuse the command queue. Except for special cases, there's usually a single command queue per device.

There's no need to reuse the pipeline descriptor object. Those are cheap to create and intended to be transitory. (Pipeline *state* objects are expensive to create and should be created once and reused, as you appear to be doing.)

See the [Transient and Non-transient Objects in Metal section](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Cmd-Submiss/Cmd-Submiss.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014221-CH3-SW2) of the Metal Programming Guide.

Comment: ok, I will inject the device and commandQueue into those classes. Thanks